can't upgrade to 23.10 mate from 23.04 mate
Here are the log output. Looks like it is a Mate problem or...?
Any suggestions?
apt.log:
Investigating (4) ubuntu-mate-core:amd64 < 1.290 @ii pmK NPb Ib >
Broken ubuntu-mate-core:amd64 Depends on libspa-0.2-jack:amd64 < 0.3.65-3ubuntu1 @ii mR >
  Considering libspa-0.2-jack:amd64 9998 as a solution to ubuntu-mate-core:amd64 9998

main.log:
DEBUG guessing 'ubuntu-mate-core' as missing meta-pkg
ERROR failed to mark 'ubuntu-mate-core' for install (E:Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.)
DEBUG denylist expr 'ubuntu-mate-desktop' matches 'ubuntu-mate-desktop'
DEBUG The package 'ubuntu-mate-desktop' is marked for removal but it's in the removal deny list
ERROR Dist-upgrade failed: 'The package 'ubuntu-mate-desktop' is marked for removal but it is in the removal deny list.'
DEBUG abort called


Ubuntu Mate 23.04 went EOL on January 25, 2024 and Ubuntu Mate 23.10 goes EOL on July 11, 2024. Therefore upgrading seems to be a wasted effort. As to the errors when a release goes EOL all its updates are removed from the active Ubuntu downloads. I suggest backing up all your personal data and do a fresh install of a current release.

I was  going to upgrade to 24.04 but Ubuntu suggested to first upgrade to 23.10... as I run a multi OS/boot system just reinstalling from scratch can end up as a big job

I do not know what you mean by Ubuntu suggested. If you mean it offered 23.10 as the next release in the upgrade path, yes that is correct today but like I said by July 11 you will be doing this again. Multi boot has really noting to do with installing a new fresh release. You can install a new release over an old Ubuntu release without touching any other OS that may be on the disk.

Reinstalling from scratch (just overwrite the Ubuntu 23.04 partition) should create a new bootloader that sees all other operating systems.

Yes that is what I did for the first time in maybe 10 years when I upgraded to 22.10.

You've left it too late for us to look up details on 23.04 or lunar as details of its packages are no longer available for us to explore solutions/problems.  If you need help, you should ask before EOL is reached or especially soon after & before the lunar detail is dropped.   Maybe a non-destructive re-install of 23.10 maybe the fix (that release uses ubiquity; alas its disabled though on ubuntu-desktop-installer used by 24.04 media)
